# Debug intercepted request in console.log (jest puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, puppeteer

console.log doesn't work in callback

```
it("some test", async () => {
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    const logRequest = interceptedRequest => {
      console.log("A request was made:", interceptedRequest.url());
    };

    await page.on("request", logRequest);
});
```

What is the proper way to debug code in a puppeteer callback?

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, you just need to set `page.setRequestInterception(true);` in the `beforeAll` block.

```
describe('Tests', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', (interceptedRequest) => {
      console.log(interceptedRequest.url());
    });
    await page.goto('www.test.url', {
      waitUntil: 'load',
    });
  });
});
```